# Sqlite3 library won't open after 250 inserts

Tags: ruby, sqlite, sqlite3-ruby

I'm trying to insert a large amount of information into a Sqlite3 database using a ruby script. After 250 db_prepare_location.execute's to do this, it stops working saying:

```
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:67:in `step': unable to open database file (SQLite3::CantOpenException)
    from /Users/ashley/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6/lib/sqlite3/statement.rb:67:in `execute'
    from programs.rb:57:in `get_program_details'
    from programs.rb:22:in `block in get_link'
    from /Users/ashley/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1768:in `each'
    from /Users/ashley/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1202:in `block in foreach'
    from /Users/ashley/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1340:in `open'
    from /Users/ashley/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1201:in `foreach'
    from programs.rb:20:in `get_link'
    from programs.rb:63:in `<module:Test>'
    from programs.rb:15:in `<main>'
```

And here's my code:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'json'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'csv'
require 'sqlite3'
require "bundler/setup"
require "capybara"
require "capybara/dsl"

Capybara.run_server = false
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
Capybara.current_driver = :selenium

module Test
  class Tree
    include Capybara::DSL

    def get_link
      CSV.foreach("links.csv") do |row|
        link = row[0]
        get_details(link)
      end
    end

    def get_details(link)
      db = SQLite3::Database.open "development.sqlite3"
      address = []
      address_text = []
      visit("#{link}")
      name = find("#listing_detail_header").find("h3").text
      page.find(:xpath, "//div[@id='listing_detail_header']").all(:xpath, "//span/span").each {|span| address << span }
      if address.size == 4
        street_address = address[0].text
        address.shift
        address.each {|a| address_text << a.text }
        city_state_address = address_text.join(", ")
      else
        puts link
        street_address = ""
        city_state_address = ""
      end
      if page.has_css?('.provider-click_to_call')
        find(".provider-click_to_call").click
        phone_number = find("#phone_number").text.gsub(/[()]/, "").gsub(" ", "-")
      else
        phone_number = ""
      end
      if page.has_css?('.provider-website_link')
        website = find(".provider-website_link")[:href]
      else
        website = ""
      end
      description = find(".listing_details_list").find("p").text
      db_prepare_location = db.prepare("INSERT INTO programs(name, city_state_address, street_address, phone_number, website, description) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")
      db_prepare_location.bind_params name, city_state_address, street_address, phone_number, website, description
      db_prepare_location.execute
    end
end


test = Test::Tree.new
test.get_link
end
```

What is the problem here and what can I do to fix it? Let me know if additional info is needed.

Comment: Can you please show us the code that leads to this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could be running out file descriptors. Every time you call `get_details`, you open the SQLite database:

```
db = SQLite3::Database.open "development.sqlite3"
```

but you never explicitly close it; instead, you're relying on the garbage collector to clean up all your `db`s and close all your file descriptors. Each time you open the database, you need to allocate a file descriptor, closing the database frees the file descriptor. If you're calling `get_details` faster than the GC can clean things up, you will run out of file descriptors and subsequent `SQLite3::Database.open` calls will fail.

Try adding `db.close` at the end of `get_details`.

You'll probably have to close the prepared statement as well so you should `db_prepare_location.close` before `db.close`:

```
def get_details
  #...
  db_prepare_location.close
  db.close
end
```

Yes, Ruby has garbage collection but that doesn't mean that you don't have to manage your resources by hand.

Another option (which DGM was hinting at) would be to open a connection to the database in your constructor:

```
def initialize
  @db = SQLite3::Database.open "development.sqlite3"
end
```

and then drop your `SQLite3::Database.open` call in `get_details` and use `@db` instead. You wouldn't need a `db.close` in `get_details` anymore but you'd still want the `db_prepare_location.close` call.

Comment: Or better yet, open it once outside the loop and close it once after the loop.

Comment: @DGM: That's another option but then you'd want to rework it a bit to have `@db = ...` in `initialize` or have a `def db; @db ||= ...;end` auto-caching accessor.

Comment: I added db.close at the end of the method but now it says: unable to close due to unfinalised statements (SQLite3::BusyException). Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: @Anoel: Try adding `db_prepare_location.close` before `db.close`, that works for me.